# when exactly django query execution occures

Tags: python, django

In a technical interview a questioner asked me a weird question regarding to the execution of querysets. Suppose we have a profile model like below:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('User').select_related(User)
    surname = models.TextField(null=True)


q = Profile.object.all()
or 
q = Profile.object.get(id=1)

l = q.filter(active=True)
```

he asked how many query execution has been happened and I replied as the python interpreter executes `Profile.object.all()` at the begging then one query is already done. However, he answered zero, and one if we call the query, something like this:

```
for a in l:
   a.surname
```

Is his answer true in django?

another doubt was about `models.OneToOneField('User')`, why he didn't use `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and defined `models.OneToOneField('User').select_related(User)`

Comment: Is that `q = Profile.object.get(id=1)` part of the question? That query atleast would have been evaluated. For the rest the interviewer was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuerySets are not evaluated until you do something that actually needs them to be evaluated. As the documentation for the class itself states a `QuerySet`:

> Represent a lazy database lookup for a set of objects.

Emphasis on the word **lazy**. This is because one often needs to call or chain methods on a queryset, a good example being a group by requiring subsequent calls to `.values()` and `.annotate()`. If a queryset was evaluated directly then we would be making too many unneeded queries to the database, slowing down execution to a halt.

As to when exactly a queryset is evaluated I would list the answer in short (for the long answer refer to [When QuerySets are evaluated [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)):

- Iterating a queryset
- Slicing a queryset (with the step parameter)
- Pickling/Caching a queryset
- Calling `repr()`, `len()`, `list()`, or `bool()` on a queryset
- Various methods like `get()`, `first()`, `last()`, `latest()`, or `earliest()`, etc. also make a query to the database