# Why isn't "SELECT" query run in Django?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django, select

I have **`person` table** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And, I have **`test` view** with **`print(Person.objects.all())`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def test(request):
    print(Person.objects.all()) # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT` query** is run as shown below. *I used **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the query logs of PostgreSQL**. You can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log SQL queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

Now, I replace **`print(Person.objects.all())`** with **`Person.objects.all()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def test(request):
    Person.objects.all() # Here
    # print(Person.objects.all())

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or, I replace **`print(Person.objects.all())`** with **`persons = Person.objects.all()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def test(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all() # Here
    # print(Person.objects.all()) 

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT` query** isn't run as shown below:

[image]

So, why isn't **`SELECT` query** run in **Django**?

Comment: [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). A queryset does not actually query the database unless it is evaluated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [does filtering queryset in django query database every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579789/does-filtering-queryset-in-django-query-database-every-time) also related: [when exactly django query execution occures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003832/when-exactly-django-query-execution-occures)

Comment: This might be a better target for any gold badgers passing by: [When are Django Querysets executed in the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70038002/when-are-django-querysets-executed-in-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

[**QuerySets are lazy**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) says as shown below so **`SELECT` query** isn't run when you run **`test` view**:

> Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.

In addition, there is also the example which **`SELECT` query** is not run. I have **`person` table** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And, I have **`test` view** with **`print(Person.objects.all())`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def test(request):
    print(Person.objects.all()) # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT` query** is run as shown below:

[image]

Now, I replace **`print(Person.objects.all())`** with **`print(Person.objects.all().create(name="Tom"))`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def test(request):
    print(Person.objects.all().create(name="Tom")) # Here
    # print(Person.objects.all())

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT` query** isn't run. Instead, **`INSERT` query** is run as shown below:

[image]

So, to run both **`SELECT` and `INSERT` queries**, we need to separate **`print(Person.objects.all().create(name="Tom"))`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def test(request):
    print(Person.objects.all()) # Here
    Person.objects.create(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, both **`SELECT` and `INSERT` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]